# json file not found when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Here is my code

```js
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
```

I tried to load a json file but it says

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I checked the source, the json file is there. So I don't know what's wrong with my code here. Help me please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hqhtkayq/ looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```
const url = 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json'

fetch(url)
    .then(
        response => response.text() // .json(), etc.
        // same as function(response) {return response.text();}
    ).then(
        html => console.log(html)
    );
```